# ReactJS TypeError "not a constructor" on running a component with Carto

Tags: carto, react

I am trying to integrate a CARTO map according to [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mqm0j22o38):

Importing Carto:

```
// Import react-leaflet for the map / basemap components
import { Map, TileLayer as Basemap } from 'react-leaflet';

// Import CARTO.js v4 <3
import carto from 'carto.js';

// Import our custom Layer component (it uses carto.js methods internally)
import Layer from './Layer';

// Voyager basemap <3
const CARTO_BASEMAP = 'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
```

This is the constructor of my React Component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      center: [40.758313915, -3.67774875],
      zoom: 11,
    },

    // Setup the client in the contructor with our user and apiKey
    this.cartoClient = new carto.Client({ apiKey: 'wadus', username: 'rochoa' });
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "carto.js": "^4.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.3.3",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-leaflet": "^2.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-simple-storage": "^1.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-connect": "^7.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

When running, receiving:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_carto_js___default.a.Client is not a constructor
```

Having a hard time to understand what is wrong here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is outdated. We moved it to another place. Please add as dependency `@carto/carto.js` instead of `carto.js` and substitute it in whatever file it's used in.

`npm install @carto/carto.js`